# Crystal Reports XI - export shared variable string to csv truncates the string

Tags: csv, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-xi

I have two databases that store information on customer appointments:

**AppointmentMaster** has 1 record for each appoint:

```
Customer    Name            ApptDate    ApptID  
------------------------------------------------
2554        Smith,Bob       20140301    100
2468        Jones, Grace    20140301    101
2795        Roberts, Sam    20140302    102
2408        Harris, Chuck   20140305    103
```

**AppointmentDetails** holds a record for each operation performed at the appointment (sometimes none, sometimes dozens):

```
ApptID  Operation   OpDescription
------------------------------------------------
100     A10         Corrected the A10 unit.
100     IA          Resolved issues with internal account.
100     C5          Brief consult with client.
101     A10C        Replaced cage on A10 unit.
101     U1          Updated customer account.
103     C5          Brief consult with client.
```

My client needs a CSV file that contains 1 line per appointment. One of the fields in the CSV is a pipe separated listing of any and all operation codes performed at the appointment. The CSV file would look like this:

```
"2554", "Smith,Bob", "20140301", "A10|IA|C5|"
"2468", "Jones, Grace", "20140301", "A10C|U1|"
"2795", "Roberts, Sam", "20140302", ""
"2408", "Harris, Chuck", "20140305", "C5|"
```

I have a crystal report created that displays the fields correctly, however when I go to export to CSV I am seeing a file like this:

```
"2554", "Smith,Bob", "20140301", "C5|"
"2468", "Jones, Grace", "20140301", "U1|"
"2795", "Roberts, Sam", "20140302", ""
"2408", "Harris, Chuck", "20140305", "C5|"
```

Only the last Operation is getting exported into CSV even though all of them display.

If I export as PDF, Excel or Record Style the file has all of the operations. Unfortunately I need a CSV. I am trying to avoid having to do multiple reports and stitch them together with a script if possible; The client wants to be able to easily run and export this themselves on demand.

I created three formula fields to initialize, update and display a shared variable that concatenates the operations together.

My report is grouped by the ApptID and looks like this:

**Group Header #1** (suppressed)

```
{@InitializeOperations}:  

    WhilePrintingRecords;
    shared StringVar Operations := "";
```

**Details** (suppressed)

```
{@UpdateOperations}:

    WhilePrintingRecords;
    shared StringVar Operations := Operations + {AppointmentDetails.Operation} + "|";
```

**Group Footer #1**

```
{AppointmentMaster.Customer}  
{AppointmentMaster.Name}  
{AppointmentMaster.ApptDate}  
{@DisplayOperations}:

    WhilePrintingRecords;
    shared StringVar Operations;
```

I have tried using `evaluateAfter(@UpdateOperations)` instead of `WhilePrintingRecords` on the @DisplayOperations, and have even tried removing any Evalutation Time command from it as well, but I still can't get the desired effect in the CSV file despite having it look correct on screen and every other way I have tried to export it.

Any help you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: +1 For well-formed question with lots of info